# Uploading a completed WP site without redoing the design/theme part

Tags: database, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

Am wondering if there is anyway to clone/move the whole WP site I've design as it is? 
Would like to avoid the idea of restarting all over again with the slider setting, colours, theme config, menu? Its rather time consuming when it involves Multisite.

The export/import tool only saves the post, tags, image library etc.

Help much appreciated. Really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using the [WP Migrate DB](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) plugin.  If you have access to the MySQL server on your new site / location (command line, phpMyAdmin, SequelPro, etc) you can import your database as a whole.

As a brief overview, this plugin does two things for you.  First, it's a MySQL dump (grabbing the entire database including any additional tables that aren't standard WordPress tables).

It'll also replace any URLs that might be serialized in your content from the old site to the new site.  (A very important piece if you plan to change your domain name).

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you! It works like a charm! 
Many thanks from the bottom of my heart =)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the export/import tool when you're using wordpress.org this tool should in my opinion only be used when transferring from wordpress.com to wordpress.org.

In this case just:

1. Change the WordPress & Site URL in the settings
2. Export the whole database
3. Import the database on the new server
4. Move all files with FTP to the new server
5. Use the "Search & Replace" plugin to find and replace all reference to the old URL (when the url changes)